# WiX: How to display a Feature element's "description" text?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building an MSI installer with WiX, and the installation requires the user to select from a couple of [Features](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html):

```xml
<Feature Id='DefaultFeature' Title="Backend Server" Level='1' Absent="disallow" AllowAdvertise="no" Description="Mandatory, must be installed.">
  <!-- ... -->
</Feature>
<Feature Id='DatabaseComponents' Title="User Database" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" Description="Deselect this to enable Active Directory support instead.">
  <!-- ... -->
</Feature>
<!-- more features -->
```

Note the `Description` attribute. The [documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html) says about the `Description`:

> This localizable string is displayed by the Text Control of the Selection Dialog.

But: It's not displayed anywhere:

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen [here](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/customizations-galore/): Add a dedicated control with type `Text` to the dialog that holds the `SelectionTree`, and subscribe to the `SelectionDescription` [event](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/control-events.html):

```xml
<Control Id="ItemDescription" Type="Text" X="215" Y="60" Width="145" Height="120">
  <Text/>
  <Subscribe Event="SelectionDescription" Attribute="Text"/>
</Control>
```